# How to make dired in Emacs use cp1251 under Windows?

Tags: emacs, dired, cp1251

I want my default encoding stay utf-8.
But when under Windows - I want to see some of my file names in dired using cp1251. (Because of no utf support in Windows)

Everything displays like: `\361\345\354`

So how can I make this:

```
(setq coding-system-for-read 'cp1251)
```

only for dired mode but not others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'coding-system-for-read)
            (setq coding-system-for-read 'cp1251)))
```

Comment: I almost did it, I haven't used make-local-variable, just don't have enough knowledge of emacs, thanks

Comment: @Sergey My pleasure, you can read something about it: http://technical-dresese.blogspot.com/2012/12/hooks-local-variables-and-namespaces.html

Comment: Great! I was suffering from undecoded utf-8 for ages. Thanks to SO and you it is fixed now! :)